# Pyspark - reducer task iterates over values

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark, reducers

I am working with pyspark for the first time.

I want my reducer task to iterates over the values that return with the key from the mapper just like in java.

I saw there is only option of accumulator and not iteration - like in add function add(data1,data2) => data1 is the accumulator.

I want to get in my input a list with the values that belongs to the key.

[image: Example]

That's what i want to do. Anyone know if there is option of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Please use reduceByKey function. In python, it should look like

```
from operator import add
rdd = sc.textFile(....)
res = rdd.map(...).reduceByKey(add)
```

Note: Spark and MR has fundamental diffrences, so it is suggested not to force-fit one to another. Spark also supports pair functions pretty nicely, look for aggregateByKey if you want something fancier.

Btw, word count problem is discussed in depth (esp usage of flatmap) in spark docs, you may want to have a look

Comment: thank you very much but it's not what i meant.
i want to iterate all the values with the same key.
in my case it's instances in machine learning. i want to collect all the instances and train the model in the reducer.

Comment: reduceByKey is a short hand for aggregateByKey, which has a more general form using sequence and combine operations. If you use it, you should be able to tuple/list up all your values for a key. However, "doing something in reducer" still bothers me, I am curious to know why it can be done in RDD, like mlib functions which are part of spark already.